# VBscript call windown main event loop

Tags: asynchronous, vbscript, qtp

Running a QTP script that has a loop with a 100 ms wait inside. When trying to hit the stop button while in this loop, the script does not stop, so it hangs until the loop is exited.I guess the 100ms is to fast for QTP to call the main event loop and process the button click, but I don't want to slow down the loop.

Is it possible to manually call the windows main event loop so the button click is processed, or is there a better way to get this to work?

Thanks in advance,

Kregg

Comment: This is a known issue in QTP. Not sure, if they have fixed this in later version i.e. 11.53

Comment: Yep, it is in there for ages and it is kind of annoying. Work around: put a break marker in the suspected loop. When the scripts stops at the break point, you can stop the script without quiting QTP by killing the process.

Answer (score 0):

**The following code can indeed be aborted** by pushing the "Stop" button in 11.00.0.0 build 1018:

```
do
    Wait 0,100
loop
```

Or did I get you wrong?